# Expand/collapse div with animation and non fixed size

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

http://embed.plnkr.co/tcTZlA/preview

Basically all I want is not having to set the height in the .slideDown class. I want it to expand based on the height of the content of the div.
I didn't find how to do this the AngularJS way so if you have any clue I'll take it.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular, but you can get the height with obj[0].scrollHeight. So just set the animation to expand the height to this value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.slideDown {
  height:141px;
  transition:height 0.35s ease;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
```

In this class remove height property then it will become non fixed size like this

try this

```
   .slideDown.ng-hide {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.slideDown {
  max-height: 1000px;
 transition: max-height 0.35s ease;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution as it removes the animation

Comment: I changed my solution. can you try now?

Comment: Almost! For some reason the animation comes only when collapsing and not expanding

Answer (score 4):

work with max-height property not height

```
.slideDown.ng-hide {
  max-height:0;
  transition:max-height 0.35s ease;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.slideDown {
  max-height:400px; // make this value higher than the expected content value 
  transition:max-height 0.35s ease;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS transitions for slide down animation and write down your classes like

```
.blockToHideAndShow{
   height : 0px;
   -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease;
   -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease;
   -o-transition: height 0.3s ease;
   -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease;
   transition: height 0.3s ease;
}
.blockToHideAndShow.slideDown{
   height : initial;
}
```

Hope It'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of .slideDown to auto. So that section would be:

```
.slideDown {
  height:auto;
  transition:height 0.35s ease;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
```

EDIT: You can use [ng-slide-down](https://github.com/TheRusskiy/ng-slide-down). Then your slideDown div would use ng-slide-down instead of ng-hide.

Comment: Yeah, you're right... the animation got broken. Anyway, I found a nice little component that allows auto height animation without resorting to some fixed maximum height that might break if ever the content exceeds that pixel height. Edited my response accordingly.